# Work Bench -Push topic Messages not Displaying

Tags: api

After subscribing to a push topic no messages on workbench are being displayed. Soon After subscribing these messages are being displayed:

-Subscription Failure: 403::Unknown client
-Unknown exception occurred. Removing offending listener or subscription.

- Connection Broken

The service then establishes a connection again but no messages are generated. Even though our actual integration layer has picked them up so we know its not a Saleforce issue.

How could we resolve this on the workbench side as we rely on this for our solution validation.

Kind regards

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). *"...we know it's not a Salesforce issue."* could be "famous last words". When you are seeking help, more information is (usually) better than less. So please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/357248/edit) your question to include any pertinent Salesforce-side code, configuration, settings, etc.. And I am unfamiliar with "workbench", so if there is any pertinent code, configuration, settings, etc. on the workbench side, please also add that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.